# How do I read this header?

Tags: java, generics

```
private static <T> List<T> createListOfType(Class<T> type){
    return new ArrayList<T>();          
}
```

I understand what it is trying to do but I don't understand this part  `<T> List<T>`

Why not just simply `List<T>`

thank in advance

Comment: Note that the `type` parameter is pointless and can be removed.

Comment: @PaulBellora which `type` argument can be removed? The first `<T>` is required, no?

Comment: @MiserableVariable I mean the parameter `type`, not the type parameter :)

Comment: I agree with @PaulBellora. You can then specify the type like this: `ClassName.<String>createListOfType()`.

Comment: @PaulBellora oops, didn't see that name earlier.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first `<T>` declares a generic type parameter `T` for the method.  The next part, `List<T>` is the return type.  Without declaring `<T>`, the symbol `T` would be unresolved.

Answer (score 0):

The `List<T>` portion of the signature specifies the return type of the method.  It will return a `List` with the parametrized type of the provided Class.

So if `Class<String>` is provided as an argument the method would essentially do the following:

```
private static List<String> createListOfType(Class<T> type){
    return new ArrayList<String>();          
}
```